# Open option menu from service?

Tags: android, android-activity, optionmenu

I am developing android application in which i have to open option menu from service without any button press. I have tried this

Activity.openOptionsMenu();

But it is showing error
"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method openOptionsMenu() from the type Activity "

Any help !! Thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this is not directly possible. A service does not have access to an activity's options menu. There might not even be an activity of yours in the foreground.

Second, not all devices will have an options menu, as you move into Android 3.0+.

Third, even for Android 1.x and 2.x devices, the only time the options menu should be opened is because the user presses the MENU button. Anything else is highly suspect from an UX standpoint.

You are welcome to have your service attempt to contact a foreground activity of yours (e.g., via a `BroadcastReceiver` hooked up to `LocalBroadcastManager`) to tell that activity that something happened in the background. That activity is welcome to inform the user of this event in some fashion that makes sense to the user and will work on today's and tomorrow's devices.

Comment: So you are saying it is impossible !

Comment: @user1155908 Is it possible that you walk backward the whole day? I bet you can but you probably won't.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself but to call any activity related objects it's preferable to add a `BroadcastReciever` Object in the activity , register it with a given name , and `onRecieve()` should open the menu

```
private BroadcastReceiver menuopenreciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
           //open menu here


}
```

}

register the reciever as follows:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("net.yourapplication.menuopenreciever");
registerReceiver( menuopenreciever, filter);
```

from the service call this
`sendBroadcast(new Intent("net.yourapplication.menuopenreciever"));`

I haven't tried this but let me know , hope this helps